# How to pretty print source code when using a AST that is generated from a CST

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, parse-tree, concrete-syntax-tree

I'm aware that its fairly trivial to pretty print code with a CST, since information about the grammar is stored in the node.

However, when converted to a AST, much of the initial structure of the source code is lost from de sugaring and other transformations. Thus how can a AST pretty print source code given that it has undergone these major translations? Does it contain references to the AST that was used to generate it (and therefore the grammar/structure necessary to perfectly reproduce the source code)?

Comment: Why do you want to pretty-print AST as a source code anyway? Print the AST itself.

Comment: @SK-logic e.g. if a run time error occurs, it would be nice to give the source code where the error has occurred. However since the AST has been modified it will not be able to generate the source code exactly as it was inputted.

Comment: When you're reporting an error, you should not point to some pretty-printed heavily transformed AST - you must print the source code as is, pointing to an exact location (line number + column) instead. How to store the debug information in an executable code is a different story.

Comment: Normally the AST holds references to line and column numbers where each node starts (and ends, possibly) so the source can be looked up. Since your question doesn't ask about a specific implementation there is no real answer to how an AST does this, only how ASTs can do this.